# How to export Virtual Machine Names and IP Addresses from within multiple azure subscriptions

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, ip-address, subscription

I have been able to export out VM Names and IP Addresses from within a single azure subscription using the following script.

```
$report = @()
$vms = get-azvm
$nics = get-aznetworkinterface | ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null}

foreach($nic in $nics)
{
    $info = "" | Select VmName, ResourceGroupName, HostName, IpAddress
    $vm = $vms | ? -Property Id -eq $nic.VirtualMachine.id
    $info.VMName = $vm.Name
    $info.ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName
    $info.IpAddress = $nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
    $info.HostName = $vm.OSProfile.ComputerName
    $report+=$info
}
$report | Export-Csv -Path "c:\Azure\VMIPs.csv"
```

However I have tried using the below to export the same data from an azure account that has multiple subscriptions but all I get is a blank CSV file.

```
$report = @()
$vms = get-azvm
$azureSubs = get-azsubscription
$azureSubs.foreach{
    Select-AzSubscription $_ # << change active subscription
$nics = get-aznetworkinterface | ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null}

foreach($nic in $nics)
{
    $info = "" | Select VmName, ResourceGroupName, HostName, IpAddress
    $vm = $vms | ? -Property Id -eq $nic.VirtualMachine.id
    $info.VMName = $vm.Name
    $info.ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName
    $info.IpAddress = $nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
    $info.HostName = $vm.OSProfile.ComputerName
    $report+=$info
    }
}
$report | Export-Csv -Path "c:\Azure\VMIPs.csv"
```

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to move Get-AzVm right after the Select-AzSubscription? because right now you only get vms once (in default subscription)

```
$azureSubs.foreach{
    Select-AzSubscription $_ # << change active subscription
    $nics = get-aznetworkinterface | ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null}
    $vms = get-azvm
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have another question of a similar nature where I think the syntax I have is incorrect